# Fire Jquery text change when selecting prefilled value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am copying over firstname into lastname field. This works well with new names on the page. However, after entering a few names the browser shows the history of names and if there are any prefilled names, or older names that are selected, then this function isn't fired. 
How could I update the lastName to whatever the firstName has been changed to ?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#FName").change(function() {
        $("#LName").val($(this).val());
    });
```

(Ex., you begin with John, Jack when you enter J for the third time, it shows John and Jack as available names. Jquery change is not fired when selecting pre filled value )

There is a bug opened on this for FF : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87943

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't rely on `change` event at this situation, prefer `input` event. Because change event only get triggered when the focus got blurred out from the particular text box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#FName").on('input',function() {
      $("#LName").val(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome ! This did it.