# jquery on 'input' function not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am copying one text field's value to the other. The following works fine on chrome but not on IE 11. Google search shows that jquery should automatically take care of this, but it doesnt. How could I make the following work on IE 11 :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#FName").on('input',function() {
      $("#LName").val(this.value);
    });
});
```

I got the above from 
[Fire Jquery text change when selecting prefilled value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24198042/1083581)

When I use `propertychange`, it works on IE but not on chrome

```
$("#FName").bind('propertychange',function(e) {     
          $("#LName").val(this.value);
```

Comment: `oninput` event should work on IE9, see [MS reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And of course `propertychange` doesn't work on Chrome, it isn't standard.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in IE11 here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hTM36/.  You must have some other issues preventing your code from running or working in IE11.

Comment: @jfriend00 Now its even more confusing. There is no error in the console in my local machine. And I have also changed the fiddle to use the correct id format that I am using which is `F.A.Name` and in jquery escaping the .s as `F\\.A\\.Name` and it all works in the fiddle but not on my machine.

Comment: Can you share the actual page that doesn't work in IE11?

Comment: @happybuddha It seems you have some fundamental difficulties with IE11. Do you have a DTD? Do you use jQuery < 1.11.0?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I dont have the actual page

Comment: @Teemu I am working with jQuery v1.9.1. And upon selecting this in the fiddle jfriendOO created, it works fine. I am working on a simple JSP with a nested object. Eg., Department.Employee.FirstName and all of this works on the fiddle but just not in IE 11. And the IE console (F12) doesn't show any errors/warnings at all). I put in an alert instead of the value replacement  but that didnt work either. So the event is not being called at all

Comment: Well, there's not much we can do but make wild guesses if you can't show us a page that reproduces the problem.  There's nothing wrong with the code you have in your question - that isn't the issue.  The issue is something else in your specific implementation.  I'd suggest checking for unclosed tags as that can sometimes mess up selector logic.