# Trigger jquery form validation if field is autofilled by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) keyup to match a regular expression agains a users input to [validate](/questions/tagged/validate) if the input matches what I want.

```
$("input[name=vat]").keyup(function(){
    var vatVal = $(this).val();
    var vatReg = /^[0-9-]{6,}$/;
    if (!vatReg.test(vatVal)) {
        $(this).removeClass("success");
        $(this).addClass("error");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
        $(this).addClass("success");
        if (!$("span[name=vaterror]").hasClass("hide")) {
            $("span[name=vaterror]").addClass("hide");
        }
    }
});
```

But I am having an issue with some browsers pre-filling form fields. Like Chrome can pre-fill certain input fields for you if the user has set their browser settings to do so.

How can I trigger validation when this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fire Jquery text change when selecting prefilled value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198042/fire-jquery-text-change-when-selecting-prefilled-value)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Because the input field does never get "touched". This would be equivalent to the focus method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad for thinking this is a duplicate, I interpreted it as selecting a browser suggested option, not the actual initial prefill on page load.

I'm pretty sure that there is still no way of catching the browser prefill as it happens before the `document.ready()` is triggered. But you can use that to your advantage.

Simply trigger the event you are catching on the document.ready event, for all input fields which don't have the default value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[value!=""]').trigger('keyup');
});
```

This code isn't tested, you may have to add the keyboard codes of a random key to the event if you use them in any handlers which listen to the keyup. See the [trigger documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. This suits the purpose for now. http://jsfiddle.net/cmrfyq48/

Comment: That works too, but make sure to clear your intervals when you're done validating.

Comment: Thanks. This works in Safari 15.4, Firefox 100.0.1 and Chrome 101.0.4951.64.